# How can I access the variable from run() method?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable, serversocket

I am new to the Thread Concept. I am doing socket programming in android. I Want to use the message that I am receiving from client in various methods. But I am unable to access the message from run() method of Runnable interface. Below is my code
'''

```
class Thread1 implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Socket socket;
            while (true) {
                try {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
                    socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    String message = input.readLine();
                    if (message != null) {
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                tvMessages.setText("" + message + "\n");
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

'''

Here I want to use message variable in different class or methods.

Comment: try [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)

Comment: message variable will be global

Comment: I am new to it can you give me any reference to how to use handler here

Comment: I already tried using message variable as a global. it did not helped

Comment: Do not use a global variable it might cause errors if accessed by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple create a handler object in your activity like `Handler activtyHandler = new Handler()` next pass this handler to the thread object that you are creating and then post whatever code you want to run on activity as follows

```
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
     @Override                        
     public void run() {
      tvMessages.setText("" + message + "\n");
     }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

For your specific code make the message variable **final**:

```
final String message = input.readLine();
```

As a side note, where is **tvMessages** coming from? Clearly is a TextView, but how does it arrive to the class implementation? You should change **tvMessages** into a [WeakReference](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference) instead of a strong reference, as using it as in your code may potentially produce an Activity context leak.

In addition, although not asked in the question, instead of creating a new runnable whenever receiving a message, it would be more efficient to create a [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) bound to the Main Thread before creating the worker thread, and then use it to send the messages to the UI. This will avoid a lot of unnecessary runnable instances.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what the problem is but maybe you are missing the `final` keyword?  The following works for example.

```
final String message = "hello";
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("" + message + "\n");
    }
});
```

Without the final you should get the following error:

```
Cannot refer to the non-final local variable message defined in an
enclosing scope
```

You can also create classes with fields:

```
static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String message;
    public MyRunnable(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("" + message + "\n");
    }
}
```

So then you would use it like:

```
final String message = "hello";
runOnUiThread(new MyRunnable(message));
```